# My MongoDB isnt working when I type mongod in the terminal

Tags: mongodb

I type in mongod to create a new db but I get this error, any idea what's going on here?

```
mongod
2018-08-28T18:06:36.824+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=41812 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Ruairidhs-MacBook-Pro.local
2018-08-28T18:06:36.825+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.3
2018-08-28T18:06:36.825+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5
2018-08-28T18:06:36.825+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
2018-08-28T18:06:36.825+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2018-08-28T18:06:36.825+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-08-28T18:06:36.825+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-08-28T18:06:36.825+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-08-28T18:06:36.825+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-08-28T18:06:36.825+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2018-08-28T18:06:36.825+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: DBPathInUse: Unable to lock the lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock (Resource temporarily unavailable). Another mongod instance is already running on the /data/db directory, terminating
2018-08-28T18:06:36.825+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-08-28T18:06:36.825+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Comment: The exception being thrown is the following: `Another mongod instance is already running on the /data/db directory, terminating`. Use or kill the other process

Answer (score 0):

Open a new terminal window, and execute `top`, according to the error, you already have an instance of mongod running, so you need to find it and terminate it.

Comment: Hi there it looks like I've had one running for quite sometime:

88702  mongod       0.3   91:12.46 25    0    42    7640K  0B     12M    88702 1     sleeping
                                                                                  
//how would I then terminate this?

Comment: Hello, I just managed to terminate it from the activity monitor